# ¿Comó evitar la duplicidad de registros en JTable?

Tags: java-swing

[image: 1][![2]][2][![Duplicidad de registros en JTablw][3]][3]

Lo sombreado de rojo es el controlador

Lo sobreado de verde el dao que hace conexion con la BD
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjNcT.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVFN4.png

Comment: Releyendo la pregunta (no es muy clara), creo que sería útil el que incluyeras el código que usas para consultar los datos que pones en la JTable y el que usas para crear y poblar la JTable.

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento de SO y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.